# Single page application using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, single-page-application

I am working at a SPA using Flask(with jinja) and AngularJS. Everything works fine, but when the application is in a given state and I try to refresh the page in browser, the server responds with 404 response: "error": "Not found". Is there a way to make this work in a proper way when trying to access a page of the SPA application through the URL?

Comment: update your tags since the question has nothing to do with python, and http status codes

Answer (score 1):

This may depend on how your dev http server is setup:

1. It should be set to always load the default page which is **index.html** such that the **angular engine** will *load* and *run* and only then it will serve the other routes (states) like *localhost/state*, otherwise the angular router would not be able to resolve the url since it is not loaded (letting the http server handle the request, serving a 404 Page Not Found)
2. The http servers sometimes serve only one level deep url's like *localhost/state*, not *localhost/state/param* and you need to change some settings to make it work, but I think this is beyond the scope of your question :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hasher in SPA. You need to parse hash string before initializing view model and based upon the value of hash set your current visible page and then bind the view mode.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a rule to always return your SPA index.html page for any routes that match your angular routes.  I'm not sure what your web server is, apache or nginx or whatever but you should be able to find instructions on how to match those requests back to index.html.

Answer (score 0):

You must have enabled html5 mode to true in in your angular js app. Set that to false will solve your problem.